# How to link navigation view with fragment back stack?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigationview

I have an activity with a `NavigationView` from the support design library and a `fragment`.

When I click on a `MenuItem` from the `NavigationView`, the `Fragment` is replaced by another which is added to the back stack.

When I click on the back button, I pop the last `Fragment` from the back stack. But, the selected `MenuItem` in the `NavigationView`, is still the same.

What is the best way to link the back stack with my `NavigationView` to have a consistent UI?

Thank you!

Comment: to change the selected MenuItem in NaviagationView you can override the onBackPress and manipulate the menuitem in navigation view

Comment: How can I know which fragment is shown? Which menu item I have to select? Who has to store those informations?